# Installation to USB put grub on my hard disk and changed boot parameters

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I tried posting something akin to this on SuperUser but I think it's too specific to elementary OS to be helpful.

I did the following:

1. Inserted USB into my drive
2. Inserted cd with burned iso
3. Booted computer to Disk Drive which started elementary
4. Started install process and chose "something else"
5. Installed elementary to /dev/sdb (USB)

All looked well for a while. I rebooted with the USB still inserted and I got the normal grub menu which (after 10 seconds) booted to Elementary, great!

So I rebooted again, and removed the USB. Now I just get a grub command prompt akin to `grub>`.

If I enter the exit command, it echos "boot ubuntu" and takes me to the BIOS device selector.

Now when I click the Disk drive, rather than it booting Windows, I see:

```
ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager
Ubuntu
```

I was expecting that if I selected to boot from the USB, I would get the grub menu, but now I *always* get it regardless.

What can I do to force grub to boot to Windows if the USB is not inserted? (I've already configured the USB to boot to whatever I want when it's inserted, but

Comment: Is this a UEFI PC

Comment: "Yes it is. I've confirmed this in BIOS mode settings." – Reisclef Feb 7 at 16:31

Comment: Only UEFI firmware has a OS selector

Answer (score 1):

Boot into elementary and open the terminal and type :

```
sudo software-properties-gtk -e universe && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mbr
sudo install-mbr /dev/sdX
```

Replace sdX with the correct disk device which I have think is `sda`

If you cannot boot elementary on the USB. Boot to the live USB / CD and type `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` replacing `sdb` with the USB drive device (which you say is `sdb`)

Comment: So just to confirm before I run this, this is effectively writing a master boot record to the sda that (I take it) grub would use to boot from? I guess that explains why I get the grub> prompt at the start. What is the risk of doing that? Would it corrupt any windows MBR?

Comment: I've since read through some online sites and backed up the mbr on dev/sda using elementary, just in case! However, when I run the first command in your answer, I get "The --enable-component/-e command-line switch has been deprecated. Instead of 'software-properties-gtk -e multiverse' you can use 'add-apt-repository multiverse'". Is this necessary before running the second and third commands?

Comment: @Reisclef Yes it is. You can use the new `add-apt-repository`

Comment: Darn, I still have the same effect (boot goes to grub> command line) after running "sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update", "sudo apt-get install mbr", and "sudo install-mbr /dev/sda". Thankfully, I can still boot to Windows the same way by entering "exit" at boot, and then selecting Windows Boot Manager in BIOS. Thanks for your help so far, any other suggestions?

Comment: Follow these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: If you do have Windows 10 or 8 boot into Windows and run the command at http://superuser.com/a/950042/544148

Comment: Thanks, I ran the bootsect command on the superuser page, but unfortunately no effect. I will try to create a repair device as per your first comment next.

Comment: @Reisclef OK. Create the repair device

Comment: Booted into recovery environment. Ran fixmbr and fixboot. Still boots to grub command line! Still no difference!

Comment: @Reisclef Are you booting without the USB

Comment: Yes, as per my question, everything works fine with the USB (normal grub menu, configured options).  However,  if the USB is not inserted, I get the grub command prompt.

Comment: @Reisclef How many disks do you have

Comment: Just the 1 internal drive.

Comment: @Reisclef Is your computer UEFI ?

Comment: Yes it is. I've confirmed this in BIOS mode settings.

Comment: @Reisclef What is you computer? Is it a custom build

Comment: It's a Toshiba S75, nope, no custom hardware whatsoever. I've temporarily worked around it by just having a USB with Elementary on it always plugged in. This boots to the grub menu and applies the config. My suspicion is that grub was installed to the internal drive (sda) despite the fact grub config was installed on the USB (sdb) during installation.

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I gave up and just bought a tiny usb drive that I'll continuously have plugged in as the USB has the grub config.

Comment:  Can you try a Windows re install